# What's the disjoint union?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm self-studying some analysis, and ran into the term 'disjoint union'.

I googled it, and it seems that it's just a normal union of any sets, but where we pair each duplicate with an index indicating from which group it came from. So, basically, a disjoint union of $a = \{1,2\}$ and $b = \{2,3\}$ would become $\{1_a,2_a,2_b,3_b\}$.

Yet, the book says it's just a regular union, and the 'disjoint' part is just a way to let the reader know that the sets in question are disjoint (or, if the operator is used in a theorem, it implies that we *require* the sets to be disjoint).

So which one is it? It could be both, I figure, but would like to be sure.

Comment: If it were a union the wouldn't $1$ and $3$ be part of it?

Comment: Of course. I put them in.

Comment: I've also seen it used in cases when $a$ and $b$ aren't really part on any canonical "bigger" set. For instance, in your case, $a$ and $b$ are both subsets of $\Bbb N$, but it doesn't have to be like that. You could, for instance, have the disjoint union of the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ and the circle $S^1$, at least as sets or topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A disjoint union of $a = \{1,2\}$ and $b = \{2,3\}$ would be $\{1_a,2_a,2_b,3_b\}$.

In case the sets are already disjoint there is no need to mark the elements. So often this is the case that the author just wants to emphasise that the union is disjoint. In other cases you want to force the union to be disjoint. In those cases you would mark the elements like I did above.

Comment: All right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this notion in a more general context:

The disjoint union of sets, is their *coproduct* in the `category of sets`, i.e. it is a solution (unique up to isomorphism) of the following *universal problem*:

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, find a set $C$ and two maps $i_A\colon A\to C$,  $i_B\colon B\to C$, such that for any set $X$ and maps $u_A\colon A\to X$, $u_B\colon B\to X$, there exists a map $f\colon C\to X$ such that
$$u_A=f\circ i_A,\quad u_B= f\circ i_B. $$

It is the basis for the topological sum of topological spaces, for glueing together topological spaces and for the construction of direct limits of sets or topological spaces.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is actually a good answer, in a more general context. It is very useful to regard the disjoint union as a coproduct, just as it is to regard the Cartesian Product (in Set) as a categorical product, which tells you WHY, as an example,  the product topology must be what it is.

Comment: @Chilango (and Bernard) Someone who is starting to study analysis and doesn't understand what disjoint union is probably won't be too helped by an answer relying on category theory. (I didn't downvote but I'm not going to upvote either)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi; point taken. But does it really deserve a downvote? I think not.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: Maybe, but someone who only needs some clarification might be helped, in my opinion. I remember very well, as a student, I  found tensor algebra over-complicated with all those multiindices, and discoverd a new world when it was explained plainly in Bourbaki's style. It may be much simpler when you leave the down-to-earth point of view for a so-called abstract point view.

Comment: Did you intentionally write $i_A\circ f$ instead of $f\circ i_A$ ? I'm actually a fan of this style of writing a composite as it goes with the intuition that you first go along $i_A$, then go along $f$. But if this was just an accident, feel free to edit your answer to the traditional notation.

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke: It was quite unitentional – I didn't write the diagram on a sheet of paper and forgot to check. Thank you for pointing it! It's corrected now.